# How to keep Unity panel always on top?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, scripts

I am working on a script that will allow you to use a video as a wallpaper. This script uses xwinwrap and mplayer, when i have the script running the video is shown as a wallpaper and with windows/files open it all works. But when i close or minimize all windows/files my Unity panel and top panel disappear and the video comes on top of the panels.. I can get them back when pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but i want them to stay on top of the video wallpaper.

hoping you guys can help me out... greetings from tinuz

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Answer (score -2):

- install Compiz Config Settings Manager
- run ccsm
- go to Ubuntu Unity Plugin and click on it
- in the reveal mode section change it to never
- sit back
- ??????????
- Profit!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't fix it ...

Comment: When disabling the reveal mode your Unity launcher will not appear when set to auto hide or dodge windows... do NOT disable this option